Setting up DSN for Oracle ODBC connection
I just installed Oracle DB Server.
Now to test my program I'd like to set up DSN (data source name) for ODBC connection, however it's not really clear to me where to find the TNS Service Name.
Is it already there in some of the configuration files, or I need to set it up to something? And if it's the latter, to what?
